# Is there any way to iterate a JSON object that has arrays and find key inside that array on a batch script?

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, cmd, jq

I'm coding a cmd batch script that contians a function to iterate a json file containing multiple json arrays to find a key and its value. The json object does look like the next example:

```
{
    "array1": [{ "1": "xx"}, { "2": "zz"},{ "3": "zz"}, {"4": "xx"}],
    "array2": [{ "1": "xx"}, { "2": "zz"},{ "3": "zz"}, {"4": "xx"}]
}
```

I have tried to use json_extractor.bat, jq and other alternatives that I found on StackOverflow but no way to iterate through an array.

In my case to help with this problem to find the json key I have the array variable name and the key name.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Im provided with the array name, for example, it would be "array1", also with the json key of the variable, for example array1["1"], that would retrieve me "xx" value.

Comment: OK, so show us what you've coded so far by patching it into your question using the `edit` button and format it by selecting and using the `{}` button. You've shown us what your source data is, so an explicit statement of what you want to locate (like its value) would assist in solving your problem.

Comment: @Magoo I exactly say what I want, to find the the key inside the array, I already said what data I do have to find it and that should be everything. I don't provide any code due to having it removed due to not working code.

Comment: Please do not try to do this using a batch file, unless that batch file itself uses PowerShell. PowerShell is built into all modern Windows systems, is much more powerful and adaptable, and has cmdlet support for working with JSON.

Comment: As it stands, the question is unfortunately unclear, in part because it's unclear which of the two JSON arrays in your sample that you want to iterate through -- or do you want to iterate through them both?  Also you say you "have the variable name" but it's not clear what you have, or in what form you have it.  It would help if you followed the [mcve] guidelines more closely.

Comment: Edited and updated @Compo and peak, thanks. Yes I can use PowerShell and I do want to search on a exact array cuz I got the name of the array and the exact position I want to look because I got the json key.

Comment: Could it be you are just looking for something like `jq --arg a "array2" --arg k "2" -r '.[$a] | add[$k]' file.json`?

Comment: What if .array1 has more than one object with a key named "1"?

Answer (score 0):

Using jq and the example given in the update, you might wish to consider:

```
jq --arg a "array1" --arg k "1" -r '.[$a][][$k]//empty'
```

or something similar, depending on your detailed requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You should not process Json files via Batch files. Any change in the input file will make the Batch file fail. However, if you are sure that the format of the input file is always the same, then the code below solve your problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1* delims=: " %%a in (test.txt) do (
   set "values=%%b"
   if defined values (
      set "values=!values: =!"
      set ^"values=!values:},{=^
%do not remove this line%
!^"
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:{}[]" %%x in ("!values!") do set "%%~a[%%x]=%%y"
   )
)

SET ARRAY
```

Output:

```
array1["1"]="xx"
array1["2"]="zz"
array1["3"]="zz"
array1["4"]="xx"
array2["1"]="xx"
array2["2"]="zz"
array2["3"]="zz"
array2["4"]="xx"
```